# pyinstaller created main file and not main.exe(executable program)

Tags: pyinstaller

I recently try to create an executable program from my python script, I followed all the procedures correctly but unfortunately it created a file and not an exe. I am wondering why.

Below is the completed message

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYOgn.png]

Here is my file that are created.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5yNW.png]

For your information I created it in Linux.

Comment: It's because executable files on Linux do not have the ".exe" ending. That is only for DOS/Windows executables. Incidentally, Linux executables do not run on Windows or vice versa.

Comment: Do you know how I should make it so that it generate exe by using pyinstaller thank you.

Comment: To make a windows exe you have to run PyInstaller on Windows. Read the documentation - see the blue “Note:” here https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html